# Redirect URL to Text File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests

Im trying to get reroute a url like pastebin.com/raw/example.txt to a local text file on my pc. can anyone help me im using:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_file
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/raw/example.txt")
def request_example():
    data = "Example"
    return data

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

So what do i need to put in the host='' for it to work? or change in the route def? thank you so much

Comment: You can try this out.

`@app.route("/raw/example")

def request_example():
      
      try:

          return send_file('/path/to/local/file.txt', attachment_filename='example.txt')

     except Exception as e:

            return str(e)`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_file
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/raw/example')
def return_files_tut():
    try:
        return send_file('/path/to/local/file.txt', attachment_filename='example.txt')
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Comment: this is useful but it is not what i was looking for. i want to know how to use the app.run function as in what should i put in the host and port for an https link